# Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3) removed xor '^' operator for Bool value?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6.3

This sample code on Xcode 6.3 ...

```
var str1 = ""
var str2 = ""
if str1.isEmpty ^ str2.isEmpty {
  // do something.
}
```

displays the following error.

```
'^' is unavailable: use the '!=' operator instead
```

I cannot find the spec in Apple documentation.
Is this specification (and I'll have to lump it)?

Comment: I cannot find it in http://swiftdoc.org/ neither in the header files, so probably yes.

Comment: The error message told you how to fix the problem.

Comment: Yes. I know it. Currently the link of release notes is dead link, so I wanted to know if it is a specification's change.

Comment: IMO Swift should have a "^^" operator because "!=" is not nearly as intuitive. Read: "one but not the other" vs. "is not equal to". "!=" works, but it's more obscure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's clearly intentional:

```
$ echo ':print_module Swift' | swift -deprecated-integrated-repl | fgrep "use the '!=' operator instead"
```

shows:

```
@availability(*, unavailable, message="use the '!=' operator instead") func ^=(inout lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool)
@availability(*, unavailable, message="use the '!=' operator instead") func ^(lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 30):

Assuming you are trying to use a logical XOR, a `!=` should serve your purpose. The `^` is a bitwise XOR. So makes sense that Apple removed it for bool values.

Comment: So how do you apply XOR to three booleans simultaneously?

Comment: @jowie xor has no definition for more than two elements at the same time, how would you expect it to work?

Comment: @jowie (a != b) != c should do it.

Comment: @jowie XOR is associative. `(a ⊕ b) ⊕ c` = `a ⊕ (b ⊕ c)`, so you can pick either one