# XOR in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, xor, swift5

I'm trying to do an XOR operation in Swift 5. The documentation does not seem to mention explicitly doing it with two boolean values here:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html

Is this possible? It says to use the `^` operation but I get the error when trying:

```
 card != nil ^ appointment.instructor == nil
```

> ERROR Adjacent operators are in non-associative precedence group 'ComparisonPrecedence'

Comment: `^` can't be applied to `Bool`.  Use `!=` instead.  What are you doing with the above statement?  Throw in some `()` to keep it sane.  You don't seem to be assigning it to a variable or testing it.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555569/swift-1-2-xcode-6-3-removed-xor-operator-for-bool-value: The XOR operator for Bool was deprecated in Swift 1.2.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to define `^` for `Bool` since it only exists for Ints.  See the apple documentation [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html).

Example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension Bool {
    static func ^ (left: Bool, right: Bool) -> Bool {
        return left != right
    }
}

let a = true
let b = false
print (a^b)
```

Comment: Here's a thought. In your main code just say left != right. So != is the XOR operator in swift, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 26):

The `^` operator is defined for integer types but not for `Bool`. You could add your own definition, but it's not strictly needed. The XOR operation on `Bool` is the same as the `!=` operation. Here's the truth tables for `A XOR B` and `A != B`:

```
A B A^B A!=B
F F  F   F
F T  T   T
T F  T   T
T T  F   F
```

So we could write your expression like this:

```
(card != nil) != (appointment.instructor == nil)
```

That is kind of hard to understand though. If the goal is to ensure that exactly one of the cases is true, I might write it like this for clarity:

```
[(card != nil), (appointment.instructor == nil)].filter({ $0 == true }).count == 1
```

Answer (score 9):

The documentation clearly states that `^` is the *bitwise XOR* operator and since a `Bool` is only a single bit, bitwise XOR is not defined on it. If you put correct parentheses on your expression, you get the correct error message:

```
(card != nil) ^ (appointment.instructor == nil)
```

> Binary operator '^' cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands

There's no XOR operator in Swift, so to do a XOR on two `Bool`s, you need to define your own XOR function or operator.

```
infix operator ^^
extension Bool {
    static func ^^(lhs:Bool, rhs:Bool) -> Bool {
        if (lhs && !rhs) || (!lhs && rhs) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
let trueValue:Bool? = true
let falseValue:Bool? = false
let nilValue:Bool? = nil

(trueValue != nil) ^^ (nilValue != nil) // true
(trueValue != nil) ^^ (falseValue != nil) // false
(nilValue != nil) ^^ (nilValue != nil) // false
```